# JS/ Call function which define in other function

Tags: javascript

I have the next in JS:

```
function doC() {
    this.try = document.getElementById("try");


function tryC(){

       //do something
    }
}
```

Now, I want to call tryC function, when so I wrote the next:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="myFile.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">tryC();</script>
```

But as I see, nothing happen. Ho I call `tryC()`?

Comment: `do` is a keyword like `if`, so you should rename that function.

Comment: `doC` isn't a keyword, so it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your tryC is defined inside doC, it's not exposed (it's private), you can do:

```
   function doC() {
        this.try = document.getElementById("try"); 

        return function(){
           alert('Try C');
        }
    }

    doC()(); // alerts
```

or

```
function doC() {
    this.try = document.getElementById("try"); 

    return {
        tryC : function(){
                  alert('Try C');
               }
    }
}

doc().tryC(); //alerts
```

Or your way (globals all around)

```
    function doC() {
            this.try = document.getElementById("try"); 

            this.tryC = function(){
               alert('Try C');
            }
    }

doC(); // call first!
tryC(); // alerts
```

Answer (score 3):

You have defined `C` in the scope of `doC`. It is not accessible outside of `doC`.

If you want it to be accessible globally, then you have to explicitly assign it a global.

```
window.C = function () { /* etc */ };
```

---

Creating globals is usually a bad idea, more so when they aren't created at load time. There is probably a better way to achieve whatever problem you are trying to solve with this.